# Problem with UTF-8 in PhP

Tags: php, html, utf-8, diacritics

Hy!

I have a problem with the output in php with umlauts. 
My Code:

```
<?php

echo"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"
  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\"> 
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /> 
    <title>Tabs</title> 
    <style type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\"> ";


echo "<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script> 
    <script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\"> 
        $(function () {
            var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
            tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

            $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').click(function () {
                tabContainers.hide();
                tabContainers.filter(this.hash).show();
                $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                return false;
            }).filter(':first').click();
        });
    </script> 
</head> 
<body id=\"page\">";


echo "<div class=\"tabs\">
  <!-- tabs -->
  <ul class=\"tabNavigation\">
    <li><a href=\"#user\">User</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#recipe\">Recipe</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#recipe_pos\">Recipe_Pos</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#ingred\">Ingredients</a></li>
    <li><a href=\"#ingred_pos\">Ingredients_Pos</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- tab containers -->
  <div id=\"user\">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div id=\"recipe\">";


    include 'config.php';
    include 'opendb.php';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM RECIPES '");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<p id=\"boarder\">";
      echo "<span>";
      echo "<b>" . $row['title'] . "</b><br/>";
      echo "<br />";
      echo $row['text'];
      echo "<br /><br />";
      echo mysql_error();
      echo "</span>";
      echo "</p>";
      }
    include 'closedb.php';

?>
```

Output:

> Zwiebel, Knoblauch und M�hre sch�len
>   und in feine W�rfel schneiden.
>   Hackfleisch in die Pfanne geben,
>   langsam erhitzen und im eigenen Fett
>   unter R�hren anbraten. Salzen und
>   pfeffern. Zwiebeln, Knoblauch und
>   M�hren dazugeben und kurz mitbraten.
>   Mit der Br�he abl�schen, Tomatenmark,
>   Oregano, die gest�ckelten Tomaten und
>   Tomatenketchup unterr�hren. Etwa 40
>   Minuten einkochen lassen. Spaghetti in
>   Salzwasser bissfest kochen, abgie�en,
>   abschrecken und zusammen mit der Sauce
>   servieren.

Comment: You know you can just break out of `<?php` instead of escape-echoing huge blocks of HTML...?

Comment: This is a character encoding problem. Make sure your database character set, connection character set, and output encoding match.

Comment: well it's better than echoing JavaScript,

Comment: I agree with @Pekka.  My bet is that your DB is not UTF-8.

Comment: @Pekka:) html entities can used ?

Comment: @Hary HTML entities are a bad fix for this problem. Fixing the actual encoding issue is always much, much better!

Comment: If the example output gave the quantities, one could actually cook this. Sounds like an interesting recipe ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These characters look like invalid characters in a UTF-8 output, most likely ISO-8859-1.

Your database connection is probably ISO-8859-1 encoded, even though the data is in UTF-8.

Fix it by doing the following query after connecting. For mySQL < 5.0.7:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

for newer mySQLs:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

The output looks like as if your data read from the db is not in utf-8 format. For testing, try some other encoding like `ISO-8859-1`. If this displays the text properly then the cause of the problem is the db content not being utf-8 at all.

Answer (score -2):

Remove all the php and echos out of your code, and simple type a plain HTML file, i don't see why you are using echo in this case. Only the areas that need some computing stays in the php tags, like the while loop

**UPDATE**

Maybe you need a different character encode, simply chose the one that match the data in your database, and you can specify it either in your html fine

meta content-type='correct-encoding'

or in a php header function

Comment: That's not my problem. thats only a test-php.How to solve the problem with UTF-8

Comment: This is not the solution to his problem. He has a character encoding issue